# How to replace a string in a thumbnail URL in Blogger?

Tags: widget, blogger

How to replace this string `s0-d` with `-w280-h152-p-k-no-nu`
in the data tag `data:post.featuredImage`

example:

```
replace('s0-d', '-w280-h152-p-k-no-nu', data:post.featuredImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

In **v2** Blogger templates, `data:post.featuredImage` is related to the Popular Posts widget, we can use the pre-existing code -

```xml
<b:with value='data:post.featuredImage.isResizable?resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage, 72, &quot;1:1&quot;):data:post.thumbnail' var='image'>
```

and modify the width & ratio parameters present in the `resizeImage` operator to meet our requirements

```xml
<b:with value='data:post.featuredImage.isResizable?resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage, 280, &quot;280:152&quot;):data:post.thumbnail' var='image'>
```

---

In **v3** Blogger templates, using `resizeImage` operator directly would be able to accomplish the goal

```html
<img expr:src='resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage, 280,"280:152")'/>
```

Normally the `data:post.featuredImage` data tag is used in the widgets is present within the `snippetedPostThumbnail` b:includable tag (There are multiple instances of this). Editing that in the specific widget (like Featured Post widget, Blog posts widget, etc) would affect all images in that particular widget. Replacing the highlighted `b:with` section in the definition of `snippetedPostThumbnail` b:includable tag with the previous image tag utilizing the `resizeImage` operator would have the desired effects

```xml
<b:includable id='snippetedPostThumbnail'>
    <div class='snippet-thumbnail'>
        <b:with value='data:post.featuredImage.isYoutube ? resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage.youtubeMaxResDefaultUrl, 945, &quot;945:600&quot;) : &quot;&quot;' var='highRes'>
            <b:include data='{image: data:post.featuredImage, imageSizes: [256, 512, 945, 1684], imageRatio: &quot;945:600&quot;, sourceSizes: &quot;(min-width: 954px) 842px, (min-width: 801px) calc(100vw - 112px), calc(100vw - 64px)&quot;, enhancedSourceset: data:highRes}' name='responsiveImage'/>
        </b:with>
    </div>
</b:includable>
```